# How to not trigger azure function app manually or programatically?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a function app, that was running once a month on 26th for a few months, but for a business reason we disabled the run. When we turned it back today 14th, it got triggered automatically stating the previous run was missed

Message Trigger Details: UnscheduledInvocationReason: IsPastDue, OriginalSchedule: 2022-05-26T14:05:00.0000000-05:00

Is there any way not to run the previous missed days?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Error "UnscheduledInvocationReason" occurs when either `RunOnStartup` or `isPastDue` property is set to true. See [code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions/Extensions/Timers/Listener/TimerListener.cs#L202)

`isPastDue` property is set to true when the current function invocation is later than scheduled(for example if a function was restarted) See [code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions/Extensions/Timers/Listener/TimerListener.cs#L90)

You can set `UseMonitor = false` to disable "UnscheduledInvocationReason" due to `isPastDue`.

Azure Function TimerTrigger uses the Singleton feature of WebJobs SDK to ensure that a single instance of a function app is running by acquiring a Blob lease, the log you are observing here is regarding this singleton behavior. See [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger#singleton-locks)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/110043/unscheduledinvocationreason-ispastdue-originalsche.html